# Appium - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName

Tags: android, appium, android-6.0-marshmallow

I had a device that I used to be able to connect to with Appium v1.12.1 Automatic Server, and now it is saying "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Marshy' and platformName 'android'. Please check your desired capabilities."

These are the capabilities I am using:

```
{
  "platformName": "android",
  "platformVersion": "6.0.1",
  "deviceName": "Marshy",
  "automationName": "Marshy",
  "browserName": "Chrome"
}
```

I expect the device to connect like it used to, but it is saying "could not find driver."

Comment: try removing **automationName** parameter and use **Android** as platfrom name instead of **android**

Comment: That seemed to work!  I removed automationName and changed android to Android

Comment: Glad to know it works for you

Comment: check out http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Installing Appium 2.0 and then installing uiautomator2 worked for me

```
npm i -g appium@next

appium driver install uiautomator2
```